# Generate Urls (Slugs) for filemounts outside the page root

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have a filemount outside of page root. Files get linked, but the URLs aren't nice, e.g.
`https://domain.tld/index.php?eID=dumpFile&t=f&f=3259&token=bee330f7ab31b608dadba275b28b6a911fb221d7`

URLs of files in fileadmin (inside page route) are perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

[image: filemount configuration screenshot]

Comment: Most probably links to public files inside fileadmin are just a real path like `fileadmin/folder/file.txt`, while the `eID` mechanism is just a call to a PHP script with some additional params in the URL. Most probably you'll need to handle it in your router's config, anyway TBH I never saw any sample for that part in TYPO3. Most probably cause `eID` is considered outdated ([see this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282822/1066240))

Comment: Are you using EXT:secure_downloads? If that is the case, you might want to try https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/fal_protect for clean URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
- biesior: Ah. Well, if it's outdated I won't try to learn to configure it anyway ;)
- JonasEberle: Spot on. Ok, I'll try fal_protect then.